# Can one map entropy to a set of spatial coordinates similar to how energy fluctuations are mapped?

Tags: entropy

I want to represent an elementary particle with a state that is only its coordinates e.g. the set of all such particles is simply a set of coordinates. Per unit time this would be shifted stochastically by the particular value of a universal entropy function for the said state.

So for a particle q: {x, y, z}, q' would be q + e * {Sx, Sy, Sz} where S is a random value in a given range which is the said entropy mapping

Does it make sense to map entropy to a set of coordinates like this?

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is that entropy is an emergent property, it becomes less and less meaningfull as you contemplate systems with less and less complexity (which usually correlates with smaller patches of space). In the end it has no microscopic meaning at all (just like temperature is related to the overall kinetic motion of particles in a system but has no meaning for a single particle unless you extend the definition of temperature). Since entropy is a way of measuring the number of microstates that correspond to a certain macrostate you can't have entropy for a single element system.

So, as long as you keep your subdivision of space large enough you can make a map by coloring each pixel of your grid accordingly, to show the entropy of that part of the system. You can also extend the notion of entropy and the macroscopic behaviour of matter to the inifinitely small by making an unrealistic assumption (just like in [continuum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_mechanics) we make the assumption that matter is infinitely divisible, for the sake of calculations, even if we know it is discrete in reality).

Not only there are entropy maps but there's also [entropy production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_production) maps that show which regions of a certain physical system are able to generate the largest amounts of entropy in a certain time.

For example here you have a map showing the spacial distribution of entropy inside the [Synestia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synestia) (an astronomical object generated after a highly energetic planetary impact and the possible precursor of the Earth-Moon system).

[image]

This is just an example from Astrophysics but there are many many situations (fluid dynamics, plasma physics, non-equilibrium thermodynamics, ...) where you want to use maps like these. The only problem is that these maps are produced on the results of physical simulations (since you can eventually calculate everything involved inside the simulation) but we don't have an instrument that can evaluate the amount of entropy or entropy production in general: we can't make an entropy production map of the surface of Earth with a special camera on a satellite, we can make heat maps, wind speed maps, vegetation growth maps but we can only estimate what the entropy production is in different regions (using temperature, knowing that industrial areas are the center of many irreversible processes, etc...).

Comment: Disregard deleted comment, thanks much!